# R Wildcard in the middle of an expression

Tags: regex, r

I want to use the pattern expression in R to find files in my directory that match `"ReportName*.HTML"`. Meaning that I only want to find files with certain file names and extensions, but there are dynamic characters between.

Here's an example: I want to find all reports that begin with "2016 Operations" but end with the extension ".HTML". Currently I am trying:

```
files.control <- dir(path, pattern="^2016 Operations*.HTML$")
```

Why doesn't this work?  I like the one line of code; it's so simple.

Comment: Use `files <- list.files(pattern="words.*HTML", full.names=TRUE)`   Suppose `words <- c('cat', 'dog'); pat <-  paste0("(",paste(words, collapse="|"), ").*HTML"); files <- list.files(pattern=pat)`

Comment: Also don't know why this is downvoted, if you can find an answer to this online, show me

Comment: I know you are not, but this is the only place I can comment HAHA.  So, your example helps if I have many things I am trying to match and I know what they are.  I edited my response to potentially make more sense.  I know what the beginning and the end of the expression look like, just not the middle.

Comment: It didn't work because you need `.*` instead of `*.` ie. `files.control <- dir(path, pattern="^2016 Operations.*\\.HTML$")`

Comment: Do you have a good resource that explains this?  There is no "cheat sheet" so to speak with comprehensive explanation of metacharacters and/or examples.

Comment: The `.` refers to any character.  `*` is zero or more characters.  So, the pattern is `2016 Operations` followed by zero or more characters until it matches a `.` (here we have to escape it as it refers to the actual dot and not any character) followed by `HTML` at the end of the string (`$`)

Comment: I think [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) may be a good resource to check

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `"ReportName*.HTML"` syntax is called a glob and is supported in R via the following which will return a character vector of the current directory filenames starting with `ReportName` and ending with `.HTML`.

```
Sys.glob("ReportName*.HTML")
```

The R function `glob2rx` will translate globs to regular expressions so this does the same thing:

```
dir(pattern = glob2rx("ReportName*.HTML"))
```

We can discover the regular expression associated with a glob like this:

```
glob2rx("ReportName*.HTML")
## [1] "^ReportName.*\\.HTML$"
```

and you can find more information on regular expressions from within R via help using  `?regex` and more info at the links near the bottom of this page: https://code.google.com/archive/p/gsubfn/